# Is it possible to get the jQuery object from a $('#myElement')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in a mixed environment of prototype/scriptaculous and jQuery. Not my implementation, but now it's my problem: I'm working to remove prototype/scriptaculous everywhere and replace both with vanillaJS as time permits.

In the meantime, let us say I have a DOM element, jQuery'd like this:

$("#myElement")

Is it possible to get the jQuery object from this so I don't have to pass '$' from function to function as an extra parameter? e.g.:

```
function foo($) {
    const myElement = $("#myElement");
    ...do some stuff to myElement here...
    bar(myElement);
}

function bar(myElementIn) {
    const $ = {somehow get the jQuery object from myElementIn};
    ...do more stuff with other elements related to myElementIn...
}
```

Longshot, I'm sure, but figured it was worth asking.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones That's not what he wants. He wants to get the `jQuery` function, not the DOM element.

Comment: Modern JS has its own built in selector - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector  Would substituting that for the jQuery selector work?

Comment: @MajorProductions How would that help? He wants to call other `jQuery.foo()` functions, so he needs the value of `jQuery`.

Comment: In jQuery, $ has global context

Comment: @ControlAltDel But he's working in an environment where it doesn't, because it uses other libraries that define `$`.

Comment: `$` is sometimes shadowed, but `jQuery` itself shouldn't be. Unless you have multiple versions loaded and you're using `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to get the prototype of jQuery and `.constructor` to then get jQuery.

```js
const myElementIn = $(/* ... */);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myElementIn).constructor === $);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the DOM element you can use the jQuery `.get()` method https://api.jquery.com/get/

For example using your ID selector: `const myElement = $("#myElement").get()`

If you just want the first one in a set `const myElement = $(".my-class").get(0);`

You can also do as you have noted by creating a cached object.  Examples:

```
const myElement = $("#myElement");
myElement.html("<div>new html</div>");
myElement.append("<button>New Button text</button>");
myelement.find('span').trigger('click');
doMoreFunction(myElement);

function doMoreFunction(jqEl){
  jqEl.find('button').text("Updated Button Text");
}
```

Here is another example: Setup: you have a document which includes an `<iframe>` (both on the same domain) and you want to call jQuery on the parent window (assume here for our demonstration it is the TOP window in case you have nested iframes)

OK now that we have some "basics" out of the way, here is an example to actually get a reference to jQuery (a bit hacky) within a function that is passed a jQuery object.

```js
var mybody = jQuery('body')
  .append('<div id="my-new-thing">I append to the top window DOM</div>');
//This assumes the top window has jQuery referenced in it via a script element for example
const newThing = jQuery('#my-new-thing');
newThing.append('<span>New Span For our element</span>');
// console.log(newThing);// commented out as too long for here :)
console.log(newThing.constructor);
console.log(newThing.constructor == jQuery); // logs true

function testMe(me) {
  console.log(me.constructor == jQuery);
  let jq = me.constructor;
  jq(me.get(0)).append("<span> More New</span>");
}
testMe(newThing);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TimS a "good-faith effort" can still be wrong, and therefore worth downvoting. I'd assume most wrong answers are "in good-faith"

Comment: WIP on my answer to fully vet options :( perhaps I posted the initial too soon

Comment: There, posted the "working" example as a fiddle to vet where I was going on this (as one option do do so)

Comment: @KevinB OP's question could have been answered that way, and this question would have been completely valid and correct. I really don't care because OP's question is getting downvoted like it should be.